# Как выбрать ячейки в google sheets в которых есть запятая?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

у меня есть одна колонка от А2 до А2500.

1. выбрать ячейки, в которых есть запятая
2. выбрать ячейки в которых только одно слово

это две разные операции. Помогите плиз)

Answer (score 0):

И первая, и вторая задачи легко решаются с помощью функции [**FILTER()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197). Это не единственный способ, но для данной задачи наиболее подходящий.

Труднее всего сформулировать условие фильтрации. Для первого случая это может быть что-то похожее на

```
=FILTER(A2:A25000;FIND(",";A2:A25000)>0)
```

(Если функция [**FIND()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126) увиделя в ячейке хоть одну запятую, то ячейка подходит)

Для второй задачи может быть что-то вроде

```
=FILTER(A2:A25000;IsError(FIND(" ";TRIM(A2:A25000))))
```

(Если в ячейке есть пробел в середине текста, то слов больше одного. Нужно подстраховаться и убрать возможные пробелы перед и после текста, чтобы поймать слова вида `Герасим`   `барыня` и  `Муму` . Разумеется, если в ячейке нет пробелов, то она будет воспринята как одно слово, даже если там написано `Раз.Два.Три`)

Comment: спасибо, выручили!!!